# Is the succinct version of P-complete problems out of P?

Tags: complexity-theory, polynomial-time, circuits

Consider the succinct versions of the P-complete problems as a Boolean circuit which represents its input in exponential more succinct ways. Could these succinct versions are in P or out of P?

Comment: Can you define your problem formally?

Comment: Have you tried reducing the computation of an arbitrary machine in some class higher than P to your problem?